# Can damaged sports exhaust lead to reduction in sound factor?

Tags: exhaust

Assume you have a sports exhaust which sounds awesome but suddenly starts to quiter or less awesome.

there are no air intake, engine or exhaust leak problems.

Could any other factors cause it to become quieter?  For example you repeatedly hit bumps on the road can the intervals of a sports exhaust get damaged to the point it will cause a change in sound causing it to sound quieter/more like a normal exhaust.  If yes which subsection of the exhaust might this happen to/need replacing?

Comment: Inner material moving?

Comment: @Solar Mike I’m not sure how my aftermarket mongoose exhaust system is designed or built but this is what I’m asking, do the subsections have internal structures/materials that give the sound it has and could the constant hitting and scraping cause these to damage/move leading to the change/not as great sound?

Comment: You describe the sound change as "sudden." Has the exhaust been physically damaged, such as by impact or pushed from the side or bottom of the vehicle?

Answer (score 0):

How long have you had this exhaust system? I am not a pro but I think I would look at the fuel trims. Your exhaust may be getting plugged up at converters. If it is getting quieter something in your exhaust is holding it back from the sound it had. I would inspect the catalytic converter to see if it were clear or not.